# Cannot find control with name: 'category'

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I see many posts of StackOverflow about this problem but none of this resolve my case :(

### My Problem

When I edit my form for the first time and save datas, all work greats !!
But When I edit my form to update the value that I already write, there are 3 errors :

- Cannot find control with name: 'category'
- Cannot find control with name: 'name'
- Cannot find control with name: 'logo'

### My Files :

*item.component.html*

```js
       <mat-card [formGroup]="projectForm">
            <div *ngFor="let Item of item.controls;let elementIndex = index;" formArrayName="items" >     
              <div [formGroup]="Item" >
      
                    <!-- Input @text :  category-->
                    <mat-form-field class="matFormField">
                        <mat-select formControlName="category" matSelect #timelineIcon type="image" 
                                    value="{{Item.value.category}}"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    autocomplete="off" (keydown.enter)="onAddListElement()" >
      
                                      <mat-option class="icon-list-option" *ngFor="let cat of category" [value]="cat.viewValue">
                                        
                                      </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
    
      
                    <!-- Input @text : Name -->
                    <mat-form-field class="matFormField">
                        <mat-label> Name :</mat-label>
      
                        <input class="form-control"  matInput #keyName type="text" formControlName="name" required
                                maxlength="20" value="{{Item.value.name}}" (keydown.enter)="onAddListElement()"  />
      
                                  <mat-hint class="bottom-element right-element" [align]="'end'">
                                    {{keyName?.value.length || 0 }}/{{MAX_LENGTH}}
                                  </mat-hint>
                      
                                  <mat-error class="bottom-element" *ngIf="Item.getError('minlength')">
                                    Min : {{MIN_LENGTH}} Characters
                                  </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
      
      
                    <!-- Input @file :  Icon -->
                    <mat-form-field class="matFormField" id="hintlabel" floatLabel="always" appearance="outline">
                          <mat-label matTooltip="Champ requis" matTooltipClass="required-tooltip">
                            Logo
                          </mat-label>
      
                          <input type="image" #fichier onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" 
                          (keydown.enter)="onAddListElement()"
                          src="{{ Logo }}" formControlName="logo" />
      
                          <input (change)="onImageSelected($event)" required type="file" id="file"  value="Choose" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" />
                          <input matInput style="display: none;" required />
                    </mat-form-field>
      
      
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-card>
```

*item.component.ts*

```js
        @Input() projectForm: FormGroup;
        itemForm = new FormGroup({});
        logo ='';
        category='';
        name='';
        
        constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
     
        }
    
        ngOnInit(): void {   
    
        }
    
       get items() {
            return this.projectForm.get('items') as FormArray;
       }
    
       onAddListElement() {
     
            this.itemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                category: [this.category, {
                validators: [Validators.minLength(this.MIN_LENGTH), Validators.maxLength(this.MAX_LENGTH), Validators.required]
                }],
                name: [this.name, {
                validators: [Validators.minLength(this.MIN_LENGTH),Validators.maxLength(this.MAX_LENGTH), Validators.required]
                }],
                logo: [this.logo, {
                validators: [Validators.minLength(this.MIN_LENGTH),Validators.maxLength(this.MAX_LENGTH), Validators.required]
                }],
            });
            this.items.push(this.itemForm);
            this.items.markAsDirty();
        }
```

Can you help me find what is the problem about my Form ? :(

Comment: Form controls need the `name` attribute such as `name="firstName"`

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. Unfortunately I have the same problem :(

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example https://stackblitz.com/